# Como gravar dados sem a mascara do Jquery usando Cakephp3

Tags: jquery, cakephp-3

Tenho um sistema em CakePHP 3.4.5 e estou usando jquery para aplicar máscara nos campos cep, cpf, cnpj e etc.
**Como eu faço para gravar os dados sem a máscara?**
Eu chamo o Jquery no meu default.ctp que está na minha pasta layout.

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.maskedinput.min');
```

Também coloquei a informação da máscara cobnforme código abaixo.

```
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('jQuery(function($){ $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99"); });', array('inline' => false));
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('jQuery(function($){ $("#cep").mask("99999-999"); });', array('inline' => false));
```

Grato

Comment: Quando submitar teu form dá um replace, não?

Comment: Como que eu devo fazer isso, @Aline?

Comment: Da uma olhada: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Comment: Desculpa, mas não sei como aplicar isso.
Tem como mostrar um exemplo, pfv?

Comment: Desculpa a demora. Mas é como o Bruno Explicou aí pra ti. (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma para fazer máscara via PHP, pegar o número limpo, exemplo 12345678910 e transformá-lo em 123.456.789-10 seria com o código abaixo:

```
$cpf = "12345675910";
echo $cpfMask = substr($cpf, 0, 3) . "." . substr($cpf, 3,3) .  "." . substr($cpf, 6,3) . "-" . substr($cpf, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode remover o que não deseja no backend. Onde você restaga os dados, passe a limpo a variável antes de ser salva. Exemplo:

```
<?php

// Remove qualquer caracter diferente de número
// Antes 123.456.789-10
$cpf = preg_replace("/\D/i", "", $cpf);
// Depois 12345678910

?>
```

Comment: Entendi.
Dessa forma eu tenho o CPF sem máscara.
Mas como eu faço para exibir com máscara e gravar sem máscara?
<div class='col-md-3'>            
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('cpf', ['class' => 'cpf big-field inline-field', 'required' => 'required', 'label' => ['text' => 'CPF', 'class' => 'small-field form-input mandatory']]); ?>
 </div>